# how to effectively modify index

Tags: database, indexing, sybase, alter

Hej everyone,

problem : I am looking for right way to convert an index from clustered to non-clustered

Description : I have a table as below in  sybase db:

```
dbo.UserLog
------------------------
Id | UserId |time | ....
------------------------
```

This is hash partitioned using UserId.

Currently it has 2 indexes

```
UserId : non-clustered
time: clustered
```

This table has about 20 million records.

I now want to make UserId as clustered index and time as non-clustered index.

is it correct to user alter index to change from clustered to non-clustered
or do i drop index and recreate.
does the fact that userId is used in hash partitioning have any implications to this?

To me alter seems way to go but I have not yet tried this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just drop both and then recreate them the way you want them. Since you are doing such a major change to each index, I'm sure the DB engine is just dropping and creating them when you run the alter anyway.  If you are worried about the `the fact that userId is used in hash partitioning` then creating each index new would seem the safest to me, but I'm sure Sybase is not going to mess up if you use alter.